# How to click a checkbox PHP Selenium webdriver

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I've a following code to check visibility of checkbox and click a checkbox. I can see the visibility code runs successfully but I cannot click that checkbox. Please tell me how to click a checkbox using PHP Selenium webdriver?

```
<?php

use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverSelect;

// wait until chekbox is visible
$driver->wait($wait)->until(
        IGAExpectedCondition::visibilityOfElementLocated(
            WebDriverBy::cssSelector('div.input-group input[type="checkbox"]')
        )
    , 'Checkbox not found or is not visible.');

$checkbox = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('div.input-group input[type="checkbox"]'));

if (!$checkbox->isSelected())
{
    $checkbox->click();
}
wait_for_jquery($driver);

$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('save'))->click();
```

Comment: Try to send the key.spacebar to the object